# Kubernetes edit secret error: "cannot restore slice from..."

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to edit a kubernetes secret using:

```
kubectl edit secret mysecret -o yaml
```

And adding a new variable on `data`:

```
data:
  NEW_VAR: true
```

But I receive the error:

> cannot restore slice from bool

If I try to use some number, like:

```
data:
  NEW_VAR: 1
```

I receive another error after close the editor:

> cannot restore slice from int64

What this error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error happens when the variable is not a valid **base64** value.

So, to use the value `true`, you need to use his base64 representation:

```
NEW_VAR: dHJ1ZQ==
```